# Как обойтись без блокировки MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я добавляю в базу Mysql запись, затем мне нужно узнать id этой записи (id - это первичный ключ, он формируется как `auto_increment`). Но если я отправлю `insert into` (добавлю запись), а затем использую `select max('id') from 'table1'`, то есть вероятность, что ещё кто-нибудь добавит в это время запись и в итоге я получу недостоверные данные. Я вижу один выхол - блокировка таблицы по записи. Но есть ли ещё какой нибудь способ решить эту проблему?

Вот мой код

```
lock table `table1`;
insert into `table1` ('','title'); 
select max(id) from `table1`;
unlock table;
```

Answer (score 5):

http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html

> Последнее значение поля AUTO_INCREMENT, которое было создано автоматически, можно получить при помощи функции SQL LAST_INSERT_ID() или функции API mysql_insert_id().

Причём если в это время кто-то вставит новое поле, вам вернётся именно ваш ИД.

Для PHP:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php
Или
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Answer (score 0):

Из общих соображений. :-)

Можно еще использовать триггер, который вернет значение из вставленной строки.

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы так уверенны, что одновременное добавление записей в БД даст ложный результат, т.е ID возрастет только один раз? Добавление в БД можно сравнить с потоками в системе Windows: они выстраиваются в очередь и поочередно обрабатываются. Многие сервисы, в том числе и многопосещаемые не беспокоятся по этому поводу, потому что поле автоинкремента, на то и делается уникальным, чтобы не создавалось одинаковых ID

Comment: мне нужно узнать id не для autoincrementa,  мне нужно узнать id для того, что бы после успешного добавления в базу проекта переадресовывать на его оплату. А вот для скрипта оплаты мне нужно знать id проекта.